HttpClient getting 403 response without the request actually being sent
I'm trying to figure out why I get a 403 HTTP response when trying to access a certain url using HttpClient in C#.
Initially I believed it to be because CloudFare was blocking any no-javascript request.
I get a 200 no problem for the same url using Postman.
I copied the cookies from the Postman request and added them to an HttpRequestMessage and sent that, it failed again.
So I decided to just capture both packets using Wireshark and see where the differences lie.
I captured the Postman packets without any issue but, for some reason, my C# code doesn't seem to actually send any request, at all.
This is my code:
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = client.GetStringAsync(url).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

When I set a breakpoint at the second line seen here, I open Sysinternals' TCPView and filter by the executable name, then I press F10 and execute the actual "GetStringAsync".
(TCPView is a tool which shows all processes on the system that are using a network port for communication with information about the protocol and etc.)
Nothing shows up in TCPView.
If I change url to be something like https://www.google.com then an entry shows up in TCPView and if I filter by the source port shown there I can see the packets in Wireshark. But the same does NOT happen with the original url.
Does anyone have any idea why I can't see any semblance of a request leaving my system?

HTTP 403 is a forbidden error. That means, you don't have access to the resource at the specified url.  Also, see this link on how to not block on an async call: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

@SoftwareDveloper, how can I not have access to the specified url when Postman can reach it and I can open it in a browser?

403 can be throwhn from your Proxy server (if you call from intranet of your company for example). In case you have intranet - you should auth there first. If you don't have intranet - you were authenticated, but not authorized (usually, meaning server sees you as anonymous)

@eocron, no Proxy, if I had a proxy you would have seen an outbound packet/request. Does no one understand elementary networking on this site?

Is it possible that your server blocks specific user agents? Try to check server settings or try to pass user-agent that matches whatever the postman sends.

UseProxy = False  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1332303/how-to-disable-system-proxy-setting-for-httpclient

Would you be able to copy and paste the complete code of your httpclient call?

@SoftwareDveloper, if you look at the question, you will already find it.
